# How 2 Powerbuilder apps can communicate with each other?

Tags: sql-server, ipc, communication, powerbuilder

I have 2 PowerBuilder apps running on Windows operating system. They both are connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

First PowerBuilder app (say PB1) is a full fledged app with all visual stuff. Users login to PB1 and do their stuff.

Second PowerBuilder app (say PB2) has no visual stuff; it is scheduled to run every 30 minutes. It process employees one by one.

Now here is the requirement:

Before PB2 app start processing an employee (say E1), it needs to inform PB1 app  that it is starting to process employee E1. 
And after PB2 app finish processing employee E1, it needs to inform PB1 app that the processing of employee E1 is finished.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also have P2 write to a db table and have P1 monitor that table via a timer.

Comment: I have missed the point that both apps are connected to the same DB... If the OP only needs to log e.g. some processing time this is much simplier than my IPC ideas ;o)

Answer (score 2):

You might looking for [Inter Process Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are several possibilities like sockets communication, COM, ... but maybe that only for sending notifications you can use the [MailSlots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#base.using_a_mailslot_for_ipc) that act like a mailbox. They are Windows-specific but decoupled enought to let different languages communicate.

I have made some [PB (classic) and Java wrappers for MailSlot](https://github.com/sebkirche/mailslot) that could help you (and a sample program to show IPC communication between PB and/or Java). The two languages are unrelated, you can make PB↔PB or Java↔Java dialogs.